# Weird SESSION issue on PHP

Tags: php, forms, session, post

I'm having a very weird SESSION problem, I've been working with sessions in my server for a long time and everything working fine. I've searched & tried a lot of changes for 5 hours before posting this question.

Anyway, it seems that $_SESSION is not updating correctly. I have a form using POST that goes to the same page and when the user submits the info its saved in $_SESSION and then I do some stuff and update the session variable. Everything looks good in the page cause when I'm done I save the session with the new variables and then do a var_dump($_SESSION["whatever"]); and it shows the updated data. But when I submit the form again with new settings and show the data of $_SESSION in the reloaded page it's still the old data.

My code is kind of complex and I do a lot more than just save the data but I'm resuming the situation here:

```
session_start();
var_dump($_SESSION["whatever"]);

if(isset($_POST["whatever"])){


 $_SESSION["whatever"]=$_POST["whatever"];

} else {

$_SESSION["whatever"] = FALSE;
}

var_dump($_SESSION["whatever"];
```

So, the below var_dump does show the new value entered in the form, that should mean it has been saved correctly, but no! Because when I enter the form again the first var dump that should have the same value as the last var_dump in the previous page still shows the original value (FALSE).

Any ideas?

UPDATE: Even if I go to a new page and just do this:

```
session_start();
var_dump($_SESSION["whatever"]);
```

It shows the old data, not the updated one.

PS: By the way I have many other variables that are not inside this if/else statement that do save correctly, and the session does update from the values on other previous page.

NEW UPDATE: I'm using jQuery to display the form with sliders and knobs, if I eliminate jQuery everything works well! It is very weird! I have seen nothing like this on the internet, any ideas?

Comment: I've already disabled caching :S

Comment: Have you by any chance experimented with named sessions and forgotten to either update all pages,  or revert all changes?

Comment: Have you checked the disk space on the server? I observed a similar issue once when the disk was full.

Comment: Thanks, but there's more than enough space, about 1 TB free.

Answer (score 0):

```
session_start();
var_dump($_SESSION["whatever"]);
if(isset($_POST["whatever"])){
    $_SESSION["whatever"]=$_POST["whatever"];
} else {
    // Check if there is a session variable set
    if (!isset($_SESSION['whatever'])) {
        // If the session variable isn't set, initialize it to false
        $_SESSION["whatever"] = FALSE;
    } else {
        // Set the $whatever variable to be the value of the session variable
        $whatever = $_SESSION['whatever'];
    }
}
var_dump($_SESSION["whatever"];


<!-- In the HTML -->
<input name="whatever" value="<?php echo $whatever ?>" type="text">
```

Comment: I'm obviously adding a form, this is just a sample code. What I mean is that even though when I update the session it shows correctly on the last var_dump, when I retrieve the session in the reloaded page it still shows the old session, not the updated one.